# How to compare two arrays using $elemmatch in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to compare two arrays to find whether all elements in the first array matches the second one.

First array:

```
var tasktime = [2,3,4];
```

Second array:

```
'working_days': [ 
                {
                    'slots': [ 8, 9, 14, 15 ]
                }
            ];
```

I need to check whether all the elements in the "tasktime" array exists in the "slots" array.

Below is the query I have tried but not getting the expected results.

```
var defaultCondition = [
                        {
                            query: {
                                "working_days": { $elemMatch: { slots: { $setIntersection: [ 'slots', tasktime ] } } }
                            }
                        }
                    ];

db.GetAggregation('tasker', defaultCondition, function (err, taskers) {
    if (err || !taskers[0]) {
        res.send({ count: 0, result: [] });
    } else {
        callback(err, taskers);
    }
});
```

Need someone's valuable help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) to find all the values in `taskTime` array.

You can simply do :

```
db.tasker.find({"working_days.slots" : {$all : taskTime}});
```